# flag for the purpose of future reference

Tags: discussion

Going through the stack exchange I stumble upon a good q/a. Is there a way to flag it for my personal reference because of its important information that is useful to further my knowledge in music. The reason for such a flag is, that I  should find it easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice simple solution for you:

Click on that star to the left of the question, and it will be stored in your favourites list.

Comment: I'm not going to thankyou 'cause it's not allowed. But you shot two birds with one shot. I was wondering what is that star now I know. not thank you.