# When to use the flags?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

Where can I get more information about flagging? What I understand there are two kinds of flags: one positive, the other negative.  Is that right? Plus how do I use them correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Αll of the flags are for reporting 'bad' posts. These are the available flags for a question:

[image]

All of them include an explanation and also, the names pretty much speak for themselves.

The same goes for the flags for answers:

[image]

There are less options here, but they are enough to review a bad post.

---

The 'positive' kind of flag you are referring to, as you did in this question:

- [flag for the purpose of future reference](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/flag-for-the-purpose-of-future-reference)

Isn't exactly a flag. It's a way to save your favorite questions, so as you can find them easier in the future.